# Content Type not being set on Azure File Store in Node JS

Tags: node.js, azure-storage

I'm testing the functionality of uploading a file to Azure File Storage with this github sample: [Node Getting Started](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-file-node-getting-started)

I modified line 111 to include an option for the contentSettings:

```
var options = { contentSettings: { contentType: 'application/pdf'}};
fileService.createFileFromLocalFile(shareName, directoryName, fileName, imageToUpload, options, function (error) {
    if (error) {
      callback(error);
    } else {
```

... and whether I upload a PDF with contentType of 'application/pdf' or an image with 'image/png', the file content type is not set once it's posted to Azure storage.

When I copy the URL to the file in my website, the error comes back saying the content type is incorrect.

What am I doing wrong?  How do I set the content types of the uploaded files to make them work in my website?

Comment: As @Haibo said, you can upgrade to [azure-storage-node](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node) v2.0.0 to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

what's the version of azure-storage package you are using? I tried the code you pasted and the content type is set successfully to Azure Storage (latest version).

After uploading successfully, try to call `getFileProperties` and you can see the properties stored on the Azure Storage server side.

And my very clear about the scenario of "copying the URL to the file in my website" and the error.

Comment: The version is 0.6.0, it's the one that was in the github repo.  I updated to 2.0.0 and it still doesn't work.  Here's what is not working, 1) getFileProperties - doesn't seem to exist, 2) file contentType is undefined, 3) I should be able to copy the file location created in Azure and put it in my 'img' HTML tag (or simply a browser) and have it show the image, but it doesn't, 4) the type being set is 'xml'.  The save to Azure works, but I can't set the content-type.  Any thoughts?

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < results.files.length; i++) {
                        console.log(util.format('   - %s (type: %s)'), results.files[i].name, results.files[i].contentType);
                      }` The contentType is undefined.

Comment: List files won't return the content-type property. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/list-directories-and-files

You need to call getFileProperties for each file to get this info.

http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/FileService.html#getFileProperties__anchor

Comment: I think you and I are talking about different things. I don't want to get the file properties, I want to set them when I upload them. I want to upload an image file or PDF document to Azure storage and then be able to have it linked in my website.  Is this not possible?  Because at the moment it's not.  The files that are uploaded to Azure storage are all of type application/xml, not image/png or application/pdf.  How am I supposed to link to my Azure stored files from my website?  What am I missing?

Comment: I did some research and I realize my confusion about Azure Storage.  I was under the impression it was a CDN when it's not.  And a CDN is what I need.  I need a way to store and serve my images and PDF files from a central location to be displayed on my website.  So ultimately Azure Storage is not what I need for this task.  With that being said, I'm a little unclear as to what Azure Storage is used for.